# Wrong Output from Query

Tags: postgresql, insert, dynamic-sql

I am unable to get data from bnrcno column while using the below query.

```
select 'insert into table values('||id||','||bnrcno||','||chargetype||','||domno||','||coa_id||','||liability_gl||','||revenue_gl||','||taxno||')' 
from bill_charges_map where  domno=5
```

The `brcno` column is of integer type, where most of values in it are null.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT) function with placeholder for literals: `%L`

```
select format('insert into table values(%s, %L, %L, %s, %s, %L, %L, %L)', 
               id, bnrcno, chargetype, domno, coa_id, liability_gl, revenue_gl, taxno) 
from bill_charges_map 
where domno=5;
```

For numeric columns (`integer`, `numeric`, `float` etc) use `%s` as the placeholder. For all other types use `%L` as the placeholder to quote them properly.

---

Note that it is good coding practice to explicitly list the columns in the target table: `insert into the_table (col1, col2, col3) values (...)`

Comment: That's pretty. Actually when i am changing the specifiers(%s,%L), The problem gets solved. Thanks for the info...!!!!!

Answer (score -1):

> select 'insert into table values('||id||','||bnrcno||','||chargetype||','||domno||','||coa_id||','||liability_gl||','||revenue_gl||','||taxno||')' from bill_charges_map where  domno=5

I think what you're looking for is this:

```
insert into table1 
select id, bnrcno, chartype, domno, coa_id, liability_gl, revenue_gl, taxno 
from bill_charges_map 
where domno = 5 ;
```

Comment: What Data Type is brncno?  If it's any character type, then you need wrap the value in the constructed SQL in quotes, just like any other SQL, character literal: 'insert into tables1 values ('||id||','''||bnrcno||''', ... You may also have to check for NULLS explicitly and build those into the constructed SQL string as well.  As jjanes says, you might be better off looking into Postgres's tools for reading data from external files.

Comment: It's integer type. Using format function as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested, By placing the respected placeholder's, It's working...!!!